# Вставка записей с удаленного mysql на локальный с удалением записей?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, резервное-копирование

Как можно перенести записи с сервера MySQL (удаленного) на локальный с последующим удалением записей из удаленного сервера?

Пока приходит на ум вариант в лоб, писать скрипт php+cron, который будет переносить и удалять, может есть другие способы варианты? (записей может быть до 10млн, и чтобы сильно не мешать работе удаленному серверу)

На удаленном сервере обычный доступ к базе данных (без прав администратора), на локальном Windows с полным доступом, т.е. можно использовать вариант mysqldump, cmd и т.п.

Comment: 1) *с последующим удалением записей из удаленного сервера?* Всех, или только перенесённых? 2) Есть ли право FILE на удалённом сервере и доступ в каталог выгрузки?

Comment: 1. Удаление перенесённых (типо вырезать-вставить) 2. Нет

Comment: 3) По второму ответу - нет на оба вопроса? 4) Есть ли возможность удалённого подключения к MySQL? Или всё, что доступно - это работа через PHP, от которого ответ можно получить только по HTTP?

Comment: Выгружаем записи с удаленного сервера на локальный и удаляем эти записи в удаленном сервере. На локальном сервере Windows с полным доступом, можно использовать mysqldump, cmd и т.п.

Comment: *Выгружаем записи с удаленного сервера на локальный* КАК ИМЕННО??? У вас что, локальный слейв?

Comment: Нет, я про это и спрашиваю, как можно выгрузить. Локальный сервер в основном включается для бекапа, т.е. slave тоже не подойдет.

Comment: Ну ты пойми правильно - нам известно о твоей системе крайне мало. Катастрофически мало для более-менее вменяемого ответа. А идиотские варианты типа "из пыха делаем запрос `select * from table`, результат форматируем в хтмл-таблицу и показываем на странице, где оператор копипастит данные в локального пыхадмина", наверное, лучше не рассматривать вообще.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-mysqldump.html

На сервере с базой:

```
$> mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
//$> mysqldump --databases db1 db2 db3 > dump.sql
```

Копируем файл на новый сервер и там:

```
$> mysql < dump.sql

//$> mysqladmin create db1
//$> mysql db1 < dump.sql
```

А потом дропем ненужные таблицы.

Answer (score -1):

Изначально я бы просто сделал экспорт из одной бд в другую, и проблема решиться, а далее - да, крон будет неплох, но опять же зависит от того, насколько загружен сервер, сколько там запросов и прочее, может было бы проще один раз экспорт -> импорт, а дальше просто редирект и на новую страницу.

Comment: См. ответ №2 к моему комменту. У автора нет необходимых для этого прав.

Comment: Доступ обычный только к базе данных (веб-хостинг), т.е. редирект не получиться. Нагрузка не проблема, можно просто например делать перенос ночью, когда нагрузка нулевая.

Comment: Тогда сделайте все ночью удаленно через цикл, в чем проблема то?)